# TypeError : 'list' object is not callable; What does it mean and how can I solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to enter a sentence in English and have all of it returned in pig Latin (following a course).

Getting an error on the line temp = strlist(a). How do I solve it??

I have an individual function which can covert a word to pig Latin and another to convert from a sentence to a list of words.

```
   def pl(word):
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        word = word + "ay"
        return word
    else:
        word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        return word

def linetopiglatin(string):
    strlist = string.split()
    for a in strlist:
        temp = strlist(a)
        temp = pl(temp)
        strlist[a] = temp
        return strlist
```

Comment: What do you expect `strlist(a)` to return?

Comment: May I kindly suggest you [do the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) ? It would _really_ save you quite some time and frustrations...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello here error comming becuase you are calling wrong function. **strlist** is list which is word of list and you have sent that list into **pl()** function so remove it.

```
def pl(word):
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        word = word + "ay"
        return word
    else:
        word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        return word

def linetopiglatin(string):
    strlist = string.split()
    for a in strlist:
        #temp = strlist(a)
        temp = pl(a)
        strlist[0] = temp
        return strlist
```